# I cannot get the installer civicrm screen

Tags: installation

I have downloaded and unzipped the files. In wordpress when i click on the menu "install civicrm" i have no answer, the screen remains.
See screencap

Thank you for help

My hosting is by 000webhost free

Marc[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the CiviCRM community!

After enabling CiviCRM on the WordPress plugins page, you must run the CiviCRM installer.  Please see [the WordPress installation instructions](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/) for details.

If you still have trouble, please post a new question, indicating a) the version of WordPress and CiviCRM; b) what steps you've taken, and which aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the Plugins tab and activate CiviCRM.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to my problem.

The download of files was incomplete, i did it again properly and completely and it works quite well.

Thank you for those who answered.

MB